# How to change DataLabels color by using LiveCharts

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I am using Live Charts for Line chart and column chart.
I have enable data labels function.
But I use dark color as background. It make the data label look very obscure.
I can't find where I can change the data labels color. Anyone know how to change it?
[image]

in C#

```
        ProductionAndTargetCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Target",
                Values = DailyTargetValue,
                DataLabels = true,
                LineSmoothness = 0
            },
             new ColumnSeries
            {
                Title = "Production",
                DataLabels = true,
                Values = DailyProductionValue
            }
        };
```

in WPF

```
              <lvc:CartesianChart Name="MidRightChart" Series="{Binding ProductionAndTargetCollection}" DisableAnimations="True">
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                    <lvc:Axis LabelsRotation="0" Labels="{Binding ProductionAndTargetLabels}" Foreground="White" Position="LeftBottom">
                        <lvc:Axis.Separator >
                            <lvc:Separator Step="1"></lvc:Separator>
                        </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    </lvc:Axis>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                    <lvc:Axis Foreground="White" MinValue="0"/>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
             </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Foreground` property of the `Series` to change the colour of the data labels:

```
new ColumnSeries
{
    Title = "Production",
    DataLabels = true,
    Values = DailyProductionValue,
    Foreground = Brushes.Red // <--
}
```